# auto press enter C# when textbox value changed as event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I develop an application and I want to run some code after press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the code successfully run when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I want a way to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> automatically when the text box value changed.

But as event because I have a problem with threading so if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the Keyboard it run well but when I write line code (`sendkey.send("{Enter}")`) it doesn't run like I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard
I want when press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run a method "image ()"

```
private void tbResponse_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

    }

    private void tbResponse_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            image();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you try to simulate the keyboard in your own app? Just call the appropriate method.

Comment: Side note - we use PascalNames for methods and type names in C#

Comment: no i want to call method after enter because i work on barcode reader and first scan is barcode and seconde"after enter" is image scan

Comment: when i call the method direct i doesn't work and barcode and app is stop it work when it change i press enter tne the method run i think it stop because of threading

Answer (score 5):

Just call `image()` method directly without any buttons 'auto-pressing':

```
private void tbResponse_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    image();
}

private void tbResponse_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)        
        image();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sergey Berezovskiy solution is good but if you still want to process it with keypress event then do like this

```
private void tbResponse_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    tbResponse_KeyPress(this, new KeyPressEventArgs((char)13));

}
```